# How to use an AWS elastic load balancer with React HTML5 page

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I have an React-app web site that plays HTML5 video hosted on EC2.  I have two instances running and I can view the web page on each of the two instances.  If I set up an ELB that points to a single instance and use the load balancer's URL, the web page works as well.  However, with both machines in the target group, the page fails about 50% of the time when going through the load balancer's URL.

This is the error in _*webpack_require_*:

```
TypeError: modules[moduleId] is undefined
modules[moduleId]: undefined

modules: (1) […]
modules["./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/arr…dules/@babel/runtime/helpers/arrayWithoutHoles.js(module, exports)
installedModules: {…}

moduleId: "./node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/objectWithoutProperties.js"
```

An internet search for an undefined modules[moduleId] looks like it's all over the place.  And I'm not sure I know enough to ask this question properly.

It looks like some people use nginx (https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/production-fullstack-react-express/), which presumably means not using the AWS ELB, which I expect is much harder to control than AWS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most streaming protocols require *session affinity*. Try setting up sticky sessions on your load balancer. Here's how to for classic ELB: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-sticky-sessions.html

Unfortunately that also pins the other traffic as well, but better than 50% failure.

Comment: I had to drop the Application Load Balancer and switch to the Classic Load Balancer to find sticky options.  Thanks!

Comment: You can still do it with ALBs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html#sticky-sessions.